# Yii2: Execute query outside transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, yii2

I need to run a query outside the transaction that I have started:

```php
$transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
try {

    //... other database queries within the transaction ...

    //Query I want to be inserted regardless:
    \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO...")->execute();

    $transaction->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Is there a smart way to do that, or do I need to clone/create a new database connection - and if so, what's the best way to do that without having to specify the database parameters again and just use the same config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585218/mysql-commit-and-transaction

Comment: What's the reason to query outside the transaction? You could fetch data before the transaction gets started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use separate connection or move this query after/before transaction.

For copying DB component you can simply use `clone` - new instance should open new connection on first query:

```
$connection = clone Yii::$app->db;
$connection->createCommand("INSERT INTO...")->execute();
```

It is used in this way in [`yii\log\DbTarget`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2ec34eb9fefa2809fd9e5d0ad9e03d1f9846428d/framework/log/DbTarget.php#L70).

But you may consider declaring separate DB component for this task (`Yii::$app->db2`) - then you will be able to reuse this additional connection.

Comment: Will the transaction be cloned as well?

Comment: @robsch No, this will open new connection without any active transaction. `Connection` component will also reset internal info about active transactions: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2ec34eb9fefa2809fd9e5d0ad9e03d1f9846428d/framework/db/Connection.php#L1163-L1176