# How to handle multiple insert requests if one fails?

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

My registration form inserts a row into two tables. How can I roll back all transactions if either doesn't complete?

Here is my snippet so far:

```
try {

   // insert row for account
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (account_num) VALUES (:account)");
   $params = [
   ":account_num" => $account_num
   ]   
   $stmt=>execute($params);

   // insert row for user
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, account_num) VALUES (:email, :account_num)");
   $params = [
      ":email" => $email,
      ":account_num" -> $account_num;
   ]
   $stmt->execute($params);

} catch (PDOExeception $e) {
   echo "error: could not create your account and profile";
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL commit and transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585218/mysql-commit-and-transaction)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete or undo the first query if the second query did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009185/delete-or-undo-the-first-query-if-the-second-query-did-not-work)

Comment: @imposterSyndrome Awesome! This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something inside a try catch like this-

```
$this->pdo->beginTransaction(); //prepare database for rollback changes if needed
try{
  $stmt1 = $this->pdo->prepare(...); //prepare your first statement for execution
  $stmt1->execute(...);              //execute first statement
  $stmt2 = $this->pdo->prepare(...); //prepare your second statement for execution
  $stmt2->execute(...);              //execute second statement
  $this->pdo->commit();              //confirms that all statements are executed and no errors occured
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
  $this->pdo->rollBack();            //if there is any error, the exception handler will rollback the operation
}
```

Please be noted that if you have an auto incremented primary key, then you may miss two auto-incremented values here because this rollback operation first creates/ inserts the data. If any error occurred then simply deletes them. So the auto incremented primary keys might be missing.